# Dependent dropdown with the following json - using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am a beginner in flutter, I have the current json response:

```
{
   "pizza":[
      {
         "type":"auto",
         "name":"bmw",
         "currency":"usd"
      },
      {
         "type":"furniture",
         "name":"closet",
         "currency":"eur"
      },
      {
         "type":"electronics",
         "name":"PC",
         "currency":"GBP"
      },
      {
         "type":"auto",
         "name":"audi",
         "currency":"GBP"
      }
   ]
}
```

data is fetched in entity

My Entity:

```
class PizzaEntity extends Equatable  {
  final String type;
  final String name;
  final String currency;
  
  const PizzaEntity({
    required this.type,
    required this.name,
    required this.currency, 
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        type,
        name,
        currency,
      ];
}
```

Piece from ui:

```
BlocBuilder<MyBlocBloc, MyBlocState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is MyBlocLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (state is MyBlocLoaded) {
            PizzaEntity pizza = state.pizza;
            if (pizza.isEmpty) {
              return Text("null");
            }
            
            return  // My dependable dropdown
          } else if (state is MyBlocError) {
            return Text("error");
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.error),
            );
          }
        }
        )
```

I need to add here 3 related dropdown lists inside BlocBuilder:

1. type, (auto)
2. linked to the type (bmw, audi)
3. linked to the type and name (selected bmw:usd, audi: GBP)